# Embedded view from other databases - Lotus Notes

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus

I would like to embed a view from another database called "Y", but when I went to form ==> Insert Element==> View==> It does not list all the the database which i have already opened in designer.

Basically I want to embed view from another database called Y, I am using Lotus notes 9 & on windows 10.

Is there something I am missing here. It shows only few local database like contact, bookmark etc in the open embed view dialog box.

Since I have few people working on Notes 7 I want to make sure that this functionality ( embedding view from other databases ) should work in Notes 7 as well, therefore please let me know if this future is there in Notes 7 or not.

Please assist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using Notes 9 on Windows 7.  First of all, my menu options is Create->Embedded Element->View... and the dialog that comes up has a listbox of views and below that is a drop-down list of other databases.  The drop-down is populated with the titles of databases that have tiles on my workspace (in the client, not the designer.)  I can't confirm this is how it works in Notes 7, but I'm pretty sure this isn't new in 9.

Comment: Ok Duston, thanks I am trying to open embedded view on browser Chrome, it does not open anything , I am trying to open as java applet, in HTMl it just shows 1st column with document number like 1, 2 and so, do you know the reason ?

Comment: A view with one column sounds like a default, unmodified view.  If click "New View" and take all the defaults, that's what you get, a view with one column whose value is the document's number in the view.  If you look at the properties of the view, on the Beanie tab, there's a field in the Web Access section labeled "Display" and the choices are "Using generated HTML" and "Using java applet."  It defaults to the HTML.  So, absent any other information, the reason is that you're looking at a default, unmodified view.